# custom page url slug needs illegal ?id=1 for javascript

Tags: javascript, urls, slug

I have created portfolio page which contains a image-slid-menu for navigation. For an menu item to appear as open, javascript gets instruction like ?id=0 appended to the url. for instance portfolio/art.php?id=0. However wordpress does not allow url slug containing ? or = for pages. What should I do now?
I already setup the slider with these pages working:
www.gransar.net/portfolio/
www.gransar.net/portfolio/design

did I complete screw up thinking this could be easily implemented?
I'm using the following: 
http://www.ajaxblender.com/demos/menu/imagemenu/

Comment: Fix the JavaScript to use an hash like `#id=1`.

Comment: # or = are not allowed

Comment: Of course they are. You just have to change the script. WordPress will never see or touch it.

Comment: when I insert those characters in the Permalink wordpress automatically reformats and removes them from the slug. How are they allowed can you explain what you do? I'm running wordpress 3.5.1

Comment: You have to add these per JavaScript. Look how the [Anything Slider](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider) does it.

Comment: you have a great point. Since my javascript is more limited than php script... I decided to give values from inside every page. 
For instance: 
www.gransar.net/portfolio/design?id=1
but then id=1 was split into its own section like so:
www.gransar.net/portfolio/design/?id=1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution using the `page_link` filter and testing for the presence of a meta key to add a query arg:

```
function wpa84303_page_query_arg( $permalink, $page, $sample ) {
    if( $query_arg = get_post_meta( $page, 'query_arg', true ) )
        $permalink = add_query_arg( 'id', '0', $permalink );
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpa84303_page_query_arg', 10, 3 );
```

Add a custom field to the page with the key `query_arg` and give it any value, if the key exists then `?id=0` will be appended via the [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) function.

Comment: Hi @Milo. This looks like a great hack! I tried and it and no longer fetches 404 error. But now wordpress is forcing a slash in between so where I should have (http://www.gransar.net/portfolio/design?id=1)
I get:
(http://www.gransar.net/portfolio/design/?id=1)
I see this is consistent with every link in wordpress and I'm using pretty permalinks here.

Comment: I'm using this javascript app:
(http://www.ajaxblender.com/demos/menu/imagemenu/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so I read the documentation for the slider and there is a function called
Open that I added

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
var myMenu = new ImageMenu($$('#imageMenu a'),{
openWidth:310, open:1, border:2, onOpen:function(e,i){window.location=(e);}
});
```

and everything is fine now. 
thanks everyone.